# How to interpret a confusion matrix in yolov5 for single class?

Tags: object-detection, confusion-matrix, yolov5

I used the yolov5 network for object detection on my database which has only one class. But I do not understand the confusion matrix. Why FP is one and TN is zero?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/kaanakan/object_detection_confusion_matrix/issues/7) issue. In short, confusion matrix isn't the best metric for object detection because it all depends on confidence threshold. Even for one class detection try to use mean average precision as the main metric.

Answer (score 0):

We usually use a confusion matrix when working with text data. FP (False Positive) means the model predicted YES while it was actually NO. FN (False Negative) means the model predicted NO while it was actually YES and TN means the model predicted NO while it was actually a NO. In object detection, normally mAP is used (mean Average Precision). Also, you should upload a picture of the confusion matrix, only then the community would be able to guide you on why your FP is one and TN is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix indicates that 100% of the background FPs are caused by a single class, which means detections that do not match with any ground truth label. So that it shows 1. Background FN is for the ground truth objects that can not be detected by the mode, which shows empty or null.